# scrollRectToVisible --> need effect on vertical line

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt, jscrollpane

I have JTable with two scrollbars (horizontal and vertical). When I use scrollRectToVisible, it return me Rectangle and this action cause that vertical and horizontal scrollbars automatically move to specified rows/columns. How can I move automatically vertical scrollbar to desired place and horizontal scrollbar should stay inactive? This method should show me selected row but my JTable is very wide and I would like to avoid automatically movement (horizontal) at the beginning (left side) of track -> simple say, I expect that horizontal position is unchanged.

```
public void goToSelected() {

    int selectedRow = this.getSelectedRow();
    if (selectedRow >= 0)

    this.scrollRectToVisible(this.getCellRect(selectedRow, 0, true));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The horizontal position might change because you are specifying a column index (`0`) and the specified column might be invisible. You can simply combine the values of the currently visible area and the cell’s vertical range to get the desired effect:

```
Rectangle target = getCellRect(selectedRow, 0, true), vis = getVisibleRect();
target.x = vis.x;
target.width = vis.width;
scrollRectToVisible(target);
```

Comment: then required two Rectangles, then set to the Rectangle from the JViewport, but plus one for good catch